# Fast indexing into data array

Tags: matlab

**Situation:**

I have a data array of uint8 (e.g. uint8(zeros(24*30000,1))) which encodes 30000 points of 24 byte each. Say, I have an indice vector into this data array for example 1:2:30000. I know want to efficiently create the correct data array for the points referred to in the indice vector. This situation occurs for example when trying to remove points from a 'sensor_msgs/PointCloud2'-message with the Robotics System Toolbox.

**Solution**

Up to now, my solution is like this

```
startIndices = (pointIndices-1) * double(pointCloud_out.PointStep) + 1;
endIndices = pointIndices * double(pointCloud_out.PointStep);
indices = zeros(pointCloud_out.RowStep,1);
for ii = 1:numel(pointIndices)
    indices((ii-1)*pointCloud_out.PointStep+1 : ii*pointCloud_out.PointStep) = startIndices(ii):endIndices(ii);
end
pointCloud_out.Data = pointCloud_in_msg.Data(indices);
```

where pointIndices is the above mentioned indice vector and pointCloud_out.PointStep encodes how many byte there are for one point (above 24). This solution however takes about 1.5s on my machine which is faaaaaar to long.

**Question:**

Can you think of any (very) fast solution to do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're asking. What's wrong with `pointCloud(:,indices)`?

Comment: @Suever: The data field of the pointCloud (-2 message) is a m x 1 matrix here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bsxfun`

```
indices = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, startIndices , (0:pointCloud_out.PointStep-1).'),[],1);
```

Values of `(0:PointStep-1)` is added to each member of `startIndices`

Assumed `startIndices`  has size `1 * n`

Comment: works! Had to change to indices = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, startIndices , (0:double(pointCloud_out.PointStep)-1))',[],1);
because my startIndices are nx1

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this solution:

```
pointsInCols = reshape(pointCloud_in_msg.Data,pointCloud_in_msg.PointStep,[]);
pointCloud_out.Data = reshape(pointsInCols(:,pointIndices),[],1);
```

First the data array is reshaped such that each column corresponds to one point. Then we take all the points we are interested in and reshape again. This solution takes about 0.003 s on my PC.